# Is it possible to have no background or translucent background for Power BI Slicers

Tags: powerbi

I saw a picture of slicers in which the values have no background. Is this possible with the native power bi slicers visual?[image]

Here's my issue
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set your filter pan's background transparency to 100% as below-

[image]

Comment: I love you. thank you.

Comment: even after setting the transp. to 100, I'm still having the issue of the background of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mkRabbani. Your answer helped a lot. However, since my slicer values background already had a color, it did not work. I had to create a new slicer, and then set transparency to 100%.